# ordinary least squares calculation speedup using tensors

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

**Setup:**

A dataset containing `m` features, `n` observations each, resulting in a `n x m` matrix `X`. A target variable, contained in a `n x 1` vector `y`.

**Goal:**

I want to calculate ordinary least squares estimates of coefficients (using the usual `((X'X)^(-1))X'y` formula) for different subsets of `m` features.

**Idea:**

Construct a `n x m x k` tensor for `k` subsets of features, then apply the aforementioned formula using tensor operations.

**Question:**

Is there a way to avoid singling out every `k` matrix out of the tensor for calculation purposes (i.e. apply the formula in a single go without iterating over 2d matrices) and thus achieve a speedup in execution time?

Comment: Could you add a working (loopy even) solution?

Comment: If you have to write it from scratch, start here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html and here http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html else, there are libraries and functions for that: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html